# Reading from video file to detect objects in video using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have trained a tensorflow model and have an input video to be provided to detect objects in it.I do know a bit of python.
so far i've come up with the following code
The below code was altered from a previously written code which was used to detect objects from the webcam Videocapture(0) -

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C://Users/Mahesh/Desktop/videosample/sample1.mp4")

try:
  with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
            # Get handles to input and output tensors
            ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
            all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
            tensor_dict = {}
            for key in [
              'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
              'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
            ]:
                tensor_name = key + ':0'
                if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                    tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
                  tensor_name)

            while True:
                ret, image_np = cap.read()
                # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
                image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
                # Actual detection.
                output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
                # Visualization of the results of a detection.
                vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    image_np,
                    output_dict['detection_boxes'],
                    output_dict['detection_classes'],
                    output_dict['detection_scores'],
                    category_index,
                    instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                    line_thickness=8)
                cv2.imshow('object_detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))
                if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    cap.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    break
except Exception as e:
print(e)
cap.release()
```

The above code successfully points to the video file and renders it , but it renders every individual frame which is taking a very long time. I am trying to modify the code so i takes the video in the path as input , provides detection boxes whenever it detects the objects in the video and save it to another file. Please help me.

Comment: Please help. Provide some insight.

Comment: What issue do you want help with? Please specify.